# PreviousYear missing rows if entity not present in current year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am running into a strange issue.

I have a table with companies with values over years. I built up a DimDate Table to use the time intelligence capabilities.

I create a measure with DAX, that give me the PreviousYear value for each company. The issue is that, if that company has no value for current year, the DAX formula don't give me back the previous year even if it exits.

here is a screen shot of the situation:
[image]

In that case I was expecting that the matrix table on the top show company a, for the previous year calculation, as company a has value for 2019.

The DAX formula is:

```
MeasurePreviousYear = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[value]),PREVIOUSYEAR(DimDate[Date]))
```

The underlying table is like that:

[image]

Anyone any idea on what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you set your DimDate as a date table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-date-tables#setting-your-own-date-table

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Yes the dim table is set as a date table

Comment: The sample data is on the bottom table from the screen shot